# how to see response of fetch in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, console.log

how do u guys see the response coming from the fetch in next js, like react in console.log to see a response and fetch data

I tried to console.log but it's just logging in my terminal and I cant even understand it. I want to log it in my web inspect and I try the "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev" but just got another problem without solving another

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best method for your question but as you want to see the log in your browser just make the component client by adding "use client" on top and you will be able to see it in your browser. Just remember to remove it later. 
Also